# Differences between ls and l command

Tags: command-line, directory

I've accidentally stumbled into the `l` command in ubuntu which is pretty similar to `ls`, although the output is slightly different.

For instance, the output of both commands in a directory with the following tree structure is:

```
Test
|_ Folder1
|_ Folder2
|_ File1
|_ File2

~/Test$ ls
File1  File2  Folder1  Folder2

~/Test$ l
File1  File2  Folder1/  Folder2/
```

Note the slahes at the end of each folder. What exactly is `l` and which differences does it have with respect to `ls`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`l` is an [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) for `ls -CF`

the `-F` option for `ls` gives file type; the `/` means the file is a directory.

the `-C` option for `ls` arranges output in columns

For more options to `ls` see `man ls`

To see all aliases defined in the system just type `alias`

Some default aliases relating to `ls` (notice that `ls` itself is an alias!)

```
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

As mentioned by Rinzwind, if you find an unfamiliar command and nothing comes up with `man <command>` you should start by typing `type <command>` which will tell you what kind of command it is; in this case you get

```
type l
l is aliased to `ls -CF`
```

so you can investigate further :)

Rinzwind also pointed out that `l` will behave differently (or do nothing) in other systems, including older versions of Ubuntu, depending on whether and for what it is defined as an alias.

Comment: 8 seconds. really :(

Comment: @Rinzwind haha I <3 aliases